# Protractor Error: Failed to connect, please retry

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

Using Angular 5, CLI v1.5, running e2e tests. I have run ng serve in another terminal window. When I run the test it opens the browser, logs in, then starts executing - but it always gives the error `failed to connect, please retry` after around 10 seconds.

We have a fake STS login page that is not Angular, so I have disabled and then re enabled Angular. This all works and it logs in and clicks around, but will error after 10 seconds.

`app.e2e-spec.ts`:

```
import { AppPage } from "./page-objects/app.po";
import { OrderPage } from "./page-objects/order.po";

describe("tslint App", () => {
    let homePage: AppPage;
    let orderPage: OrderPage;

    beforeEach(() => {
        homePage = new AppPage();
        orderPage = new OrderPage();
    });

    it("should navigate around orders", () => {
        homePage.disableAngular();
        homePage.navigateToSTS();
        homePage.selectUser();
        homePage.clickSignIn();
        homePage.enableAngular();
        expect(homePage.getParagraphText()).toEqual("First LAST");
        homePage.clickOrder();
        expect(orderPage.selectHeader()).toEqual("Orders");
        orderDashboardPage.clickCreateOrder();

        [.... etc]
    });
});
```

`protractor.conf.js`:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require("jasmine-spec-reporter");

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 21000,
    specs: ["./js/e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts"],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome"
    },
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost/",
    framework: "jasmine",
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,        
        print: function() {}
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require("ts-node").register({
            project: "./js/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    },
    debug: true,
    nodeDebug: true,
    troubleshoot: true,
};
```

Terminal Output:

```
C:\Code\>ng e2e -s false
(node:15364) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[11:28:37] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Code\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.33.zip
[11:28:37] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.33.zip
[11:28:37] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.33.exe up to date
[11:28:37] D/launcher - Running with --troubleshoot
[11:28:37] D/launcher - Protractor version: 5.2.0
[11:28:37] D/launcher - Your base url for tests is http://localhost/
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/13448c66-b08b-448f-8838-0b1ff17c53c5
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[11:28:37] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
(node:18304) [DEP0068] DeprecationWarning: `node debug` is deprecated. Please use `node inspect` instead.
connecting to localhost:5858 ...[11:28:38] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12608/devtools/browser/3763eefb-c5ae-4f7d-82bd-c99d98aee99c
.[11:28:39] D/runner - WebDriver session successfully started with capabilities Capabilities {
  map_:
   Map {
     'acceptSslCerts' => true,
     'applicationCacheEnabled' => false,
     'browserConnectionEnabled' => false,
     'browserName' => 'chrome',
     'chrome' => { chromedriverVersion: '2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f)',
     userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\CONTWE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir20368_5804' },
     'cssSelectorsEnabled' => true,
     'databaseEnabled' => false,
     'handlesAlerts' => true,
     'hasTouchScreen' => false,
     'javascriptEnabled' => true,
     'locationContextEnabled' => true,
     'mobileEmulationEnabled' => false,
     'nativeEvents' => true,
     'networkConnectionEnabled' => false,
     'pageLoadStrategy' => 'normal',
     'platform' => 'Windows NT',
     'rotatable' => false,
     'setWindowRect' => true,
     'takesHeapSnapshot' => true,
     'takesScreenshot' => true,
     'unexpectedAlertBehaviour' => '',
     'version' => '62.0.3202.94',
     'webStorageEnabled' => true } }
[11:28:39] D/runner - Running with spec files C:\Code\js\e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts
........ failed to connect, please retry
[11:28:52] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `webdriver-manager update` to install a local chromedriver, then you don't need to set the **chromeDriver** setting in protractor config

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  chromeDriver: chromeDriverPath, <--
  specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platform: 'ANY',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--test-type']
    }
  }
}
```